# export * and fat arrow functions not working in react-native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using the `export * ...` and `someFunc = () => {}` in JS classes. However, for some reason they aren't working in react-native.

This is my action creator in `SomeActionFile.js`:

```
export const userChangedSummary = (summaryText) => {
    return {
        type: 'SUMMARY_CHANGED',
        payload: summaryText
    };
};
```

Then in my `actions/index.js` I am doing this:

`export * from './someDirectory/SomeActionFile';`

In my Component I am simply calling the function in my action creator:

```
    import { setUserCountry } from '../../actions';

    class SomeComponent extends PureComponent<{}> {
    summaryChanged = (summary) => {
            this.props.userChangedSummary(summary);
        };

renderYears = YearsFuture.map((item, i) => {
        return <Picker.Item key={i} value={item} label={item}/>
    });

     render() {
            return (

                                    <Input
                                        placeholder={'About'}
                                        onChangeText={this.summaryChanged.bind(this)}
                                        value={this.props.userProfile.summary}
                                        maxLength={240}
                                        multiline={true}
                                    />

<Picker style={{flex: 1,}}
                                        onValueChange={this.onValueToYearChange}
                                        selectedValue={this.props.educationToYear}>
                                    {this.renderYears}
                                </Picker>
            );
        }

    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setUserCountry})(SomeComponent);
```

this displays an error: `userChangedSummary is undefined`

But when I import like this `import { setUserCountry } from '../../someDirectory/SomeActionFile';` It works. So I dont know whats wrong.

Also `renderYears also goes undefined`

All this was working fine until yesterday. I dont know whats wrong now. :/

Any ideas???? Completely stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no Action defined called

> setuserCountry 
>    in the someactionfile.js

Comment: Nope that's not the case at all

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added `userChangedSummary` as a prop for SomeComponent.

The line below shows that you are only mapping one action, setUserCountry, to SomeComponent.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setUserCountry })(SomeComponent);
```

Inside of the SomeComponent file, try importing `userChangedSummary`.

```
import { setUserCountry, userChangedSummary } from '../../actions';
```

I would also advise using `bindActionCreators()`

> Turns an object whose values are action creators, into an object with the same keys, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly.

Source: https://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html

Simply add, to SomeComponent

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

...


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  setUserCountry, 
  userChangedSummary
}, dispatch);

...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeComponent);
```

This will allow you to execute `this.props.userChangedSummary()` and by using `bindActionCreators`, it'll be automagically dispatched.